# DOS command to remove a space from a file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-rename, removing-whitespace

I have 1 file in folder `\\myserver\myfolder` whose file name has a space like
`First Name_20180810.csv`. 
I need a command that will run daily to rename
`First Name_{date}.csv` to `FirstName_{date}.csv`.

The date in file name changes daily. For example, today the file name is
`First Name_20180812.csv`, tomorrow the file name is `First Name_20180813.csv`.

How can I rename `First Name_{date}.csv` to be `FirstName_{date}.csv` in folder `\\myserver\myfolder` ?

Thank you.

Comment: The central point in this question is to remove _one space_ placed _at any place_ from a file name. Is this right? If so, then the _structure_ of the file name is _always_ the same (and don't change daily)...

Comment: `dos != cmd` :-)

Comment: DOS only did 8.3 file names.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: [Windows cmd is not DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 2):

the `ren` command can use wildcards, but it acts unexpected:

From `First Name_20180812.csv`,

```
ren "first Name_*" FirstName_*
```

would generate `FirstName__20180812.csv`. (the length of the wildcard replacing string has the same length)

That leaves you to two options: either don't *remove* the space but *replace* it like:

```
ren "first Name_*" "First-Name_*"
```

or use a short script to remove the space (actually: remove *all* spaces):

```
@echo off
REM for /l %%i in (4 1 9) do break>"First Name_2018081%%i.csv"
REM (uncomment above line to generate some testfiles)

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in ("first name_*") do (
  set "file=%%A"
  ren "%%A" "!file: =!"
)
```

Comment: @Aacini: Yes, I need to remove one space placed at any place from a file name and the structure of the file name is always the same. But, there is a date in the file name, so today the file name will be First Name_081318.csv, tomorrow it will be First Name_081418.csv.

Comment: @Ross Ridge: It's Windows

Comment: Thank you ! This command works: ren "\\myserver\myfolder\First Name_{askteriks}" First-Name_{asteriks}  @Stephan